# error "the following errors must be resolved" with msmq

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msmq

I'm working in VS 2012 RC.

I have a class which inherits from `MessageQueue` (add reference to System.Messaging.dll).  When I want to open it in the solution explorer I see the following error:

```
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following 
errors must be resolved: "Format name is invalid. "
```

The project builds.  This happens only when I open the class with a double click.  When I click with the left button and click "open", this error doesn't happen.

When I delete `: MessageQueue` from the code below, the problem is fixed.

Code:

```
public class QueueMSMQ : MessageQueue
{
  //my own class
}
```

What does the error mean and what is going on?

Comment: "Format name is invalid" sounds like a constructor was trying to create a queue handle with an incorrect queue name.

Comment: it is building. I added this information! thanks!

Comment: What's the `Type` of the exception (e.g. `ArgumentNullException`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the System.Messaging.MessageQueue inherits from Component class, your sub class will be treated as Component and use Form Editor as the default editor. To workaround this, you can right-click this class, choose Open With, in the Open With dialog set Microsoft Visual Studio Editor as the default editor. More details you can find here : [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/93cb9a43-3399-459d-bd1e-bcda2156d30d/)